# Circular definition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I am new to logic and studying it by Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2nd edition). For question 3.3.1 in the books, which states

> Show that in the structure $(\mathbb{N}; \cdot, E)$ we can define the addition relation $\{\langle m, n, m+n\rangle \mid m, n \text{ in }\mathbb{N}\}$. Conclude that in this structure $\{0\}$, the ordering relation $<$, and the successor relation $\{\langle n, S(n)\rangle \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are definable.

So I think we should first define $0$ since clearly we want to use $x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$ but $0^0$ causes trouble. With knowing $0$ we can define $+$ by $\forall x(x \neq 0 \land xEv_1 \cdot xEv_2 = xEv_3)$.

However I found someone writing his/her [answer](http://dbfin.com/logic/enderton/chapter-3/section-3-3-a-subtheory-of-number-theory/problem-1-solution/) on the internet. S/he used $\mathbf{0}$ and $S(n)$ to define $+$! I don't understand. I know boldface $\mathbf{0}$ means constant symbol, but it's not in $(\mathbb{N}; \cdot, E)$. Neither is $S(n)$. Then s/he says we can define $\{0\}$ and $S$ by $(\mathbb{N}; +)$. Is it wrong?

Further question:

If $\mathbf{0}$ is in the structure, can I simply define $\{0\}$ by $v=\mathbf{0}$? I can't see any reason to go back to $(\mathbb{N}; +)$ to define it.

Comment: S/he was simply doing an entirely different exercise.  She was starting with 0 and S(n) to define N and addition.  You are asked to do the exact opposite.  Math is axiomatic and there isn't an objective natural starting point one must begin at.  The goal is to keep the axioms and definitions basic and minimal and derive all else.  0 and S (n) derive N,+ is fairly constructivist.  N,+ is more algebraic and axiomatic (and maybe easier)

Comment: @fleablood It is indeed the solution (though not official) to the book as the website says so I feel very strange. And, well, the exactly same question statement is printed on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Comment* to :

> boldface $\mathbf{0}$ means constant symbol, but it's not in $(\mathbb N;⋅,E)$.

Exactly; in the "outer" world there is the *number* $0$ but the language has no "name" $\mathbf{0}$ for it.

> If $\mathbf{0}$ is in the structure, can I simply define $\{ 0 \}$ by (the formula) $v=\mathbf{0}$ ?

No; $0$ (the number) is in the structure, but the *constant* $\mathbf{0}$ is not in the langugae. Thus, the formula $v=\mathbf{0}$ is not available.

Thus, the first task is to find a suitable formula defining the number, i.e. identifying univocally it.

Possible solution; having defined $+$, we can say that : $\exists x  \forall y \ (y+x=y)$ can be a plausible definition of $0$.

See page 90 : **Definability in a Structure**, regarding the definability of
a subset of the universe or of a relation on the universe. Applied to our example :

> $$\{ a \mid \ \vDash_{\mathbb N} \varphi[[a]] \}.$$

Comment: So I suppose $\mathbf{0}$ is a concept about a language rather than about a structure? Next question is, does $\lnot \exists x vEv=x$ properly defines $\{0\}$?

Comment: @MonkeyKing - Yes, $\mathbf{0}$ is a *constant* symbol, and thus it is part of the language. Regarding $0$, it depends if we assume that $0^0=1$ ... see [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).